# How to extract meaning of colloquial phrases and expressions in English

Tags: nlp, expression, sentiment-analysis, word-sense-disambiguation, phrases

I am looking into extracting the meaning of expressions used in everyday speaking. For an instance, it is apparent to a human that the sentence `The meal we had at restaurant A tasted like food at my granny's.` means that the food was tasty.

How can I extract this meaning using a tool or a technique?

The method I've found so far is to first extract phrases using Stanford CoreNLP POS tagging, and use a Word Sense Induction tool to derive the meaning of the phrase. However, as WSI tools are used to get the meaning of words when they have multiple meanings, I am not sure if it would be the best tool to use.

What would be the best method to extract the meanings? Or is there any tool that can both identify phrases and extract their meanings?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search for sentiment analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you pose is a difficult one. You should use tools from [Sentiment Analysis](https://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/) to get a gist of the sentence emotional message. There are more sophisticated approaches which attempt at extracting what quality is assigned to what object in the sentence (this you can get from POS-tagged sentences + some hand-crafted [Information Extraction](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html) rules).

However, you may want to also explore paraphrasing the more formal language to the common one and look for those phrases. For that you would need to a good (exhaustive) dictionary of common expressions to start with (there are sometimes slang dictionaries available - but I am not aware of any for English right now). You could then map the colloquial ones to some more formal ones which are likely to be caught by some embedding space (frequently used in Sentiment Analysis).

Comment: @Fleur - did it help you? If so, could you please accept the answer?